# How can i convert seconds to minutes in PlayerPrefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to show the high time score on my game over screen, so i needed to use PlayerPrefs to store the high score. The problem is i can't convert seconds to minutes when i use PlayerPrefs.GetFloat().ToString() method. You know this ((@"mm:ss)) method works with TimeSpan but PlayerPrefs.GetFloat() is a float value so i can't use that method either.

I tried .ToString(string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds)) but it shows uncorrently(01:41 instead of 02:21, i think it is about 141 seconds = 2 mins 21 sec). Please help me.

```
    private DateTime startTime;
    private TimeSpan gameLength;

    private void Start()
{
    startTime = DateTime.Now;
    gameLength = DateTime.Now - startTime;
    string minutes = gameLength.Minutes.ToString("00");
    string seconds = gameLength.Seconds.ToString("00");
    mostTimeSurvived.text = 
    PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighTime").ToString(string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds));
}

    public void Finish()
{
    finished = true;
    gameLength = DateTime.Now - startTime;
    float gameTimer = (float)gameLength.TotalSeconds;

    if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("HighTime") < gameTimer)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("HighTime", gameTimer);
        mostTimeSurvived.text = gameLength.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  using System;
  //...

  TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("key"));
  Debug.Log(time.Minutes + ":" + time.Seconds);
```